# Perl Script causing Kernel Panic

Tags: linux, perl, oop, ssh, telnet

I made a plugin for Nagios/Icinga that parses networking device logs for strings but it's causing kernel panics in large environments. The full code can be found [here](https://github.com/cflinspach/parse_logs). I've tried reinstalling the kernel and some packages but it still persists. It's also running on another server just fine, but that server monitors less hosts. How can I troubleshoot the Oops to fix the code or repair the server?

The script uses Net::OpenSSH to connect to different networking devices and run "sh log", an example excerpt is:

```
my $cisco_cmd = 'sh log ';  

# SSH
if ($socket) {
    SSH();

    # Cisco SSH command
    my $ssh_session = $ssh->system({stdout_fh=> $stdout_fh}, $cisco_cmd);
}
sub SSH{
    $ssh = Net::OpenSSH->new($host, user=>$username, 
                                    password=>$password, 
                                    timeout => 30, 
                                    master_stdout_fh => $stdout_fh,
                                    master_stderr_fh => $stdout_fh,
                                    master_opts => [-o => "KexAlgorithms=+diffie-hellman-group1-sha1",
                                                    -o => "HostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-dss",
                                                    -o => "StrictHostKeyChecking no"]);
    if ($ssh->error) {
            print "Unknown - Unable to connect to remote host: ". $ssh->error . "\n";
            exit 3;
        };

    return $ssh;
}
```

Over time syslog will start logging Oops's before it goes into kernel panic.

The Oops is:

```
Oct  6 14:11:43 icinga1 kernel: [359392.196625] BUG: unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference at           (null)
Oct  6 14:11:43 icinga1 kernel: [359392.196632] IP: [<ffffffff814fa7c5>] tty_ioctl+0x375/0xc40
Oct  6 14:11:43 icinga1 kernel: [359392.196640] PGD 0 
Oct  6 14:11:43 icinga1 kernel: [359392.196642] Oops: 0000 [#1] SMP 
Oct  6 14:11:43 icinga1 kernel: [359392.196645] Modules linked in: vmw_vsock_vmci_transport vsock coretemp crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel aesni_intel aes_x86_64 lrw gf128mul glue_helper ablk_helper cryptd vmw_balloon input_leds joydev serio_raw shpchp i2c_piix4 vmw_vmci 8250_fintek mac_hid sunrpc parport_pc ppdev lp parport autofs4 vmw_pvscsi vmwgfx ttm drm_kms_helper syscopyarea psmouse sysfillrect sysimgblt mptspi fb_sys_fops mptscsih drm mptbase ahci vmxnet3 libahci scsi_transport_spi pata_acpi floppy fjes
Oct  6 14:11:43 icinga1 kernel: [359392.196672] CPU: 1 PID: 21451 Comm: ssh Not tainted 4.4.0-96-generic #119-Ubuntu
Oct  6 14:11:43 icinga1 kernel: [359392.196684] Hardware name: VMware, Inc. VMware Virtual Platform/440BX Desktop Reference Platform, BIOS 6.00 09/21/2015
Oct  6 14:11:43 icinga1 kernel: [359392.196686] task: ffff88042d008000 ti: ffff88033194c000 task.ti: ffff88033194c000
Oct  6 14:11:43 icinga1 kernel: [359392.196688] RIP: 0010:[<ffffffff814fa7c5>]  [<ffffffff814fa7c5>] tty_ioctl+0x375/0xc40
Oct  6 14:11:43 icinga1 kernel: [359392.196691] RSP: 0018:ffff88033194fdf0  EFLAGS: 00010246
Oct  6 14:11:43 icinga1 kernel: [359392.196692] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: ffff8803c8aec800 RCX: fffffffeffffffff
Oct  6 14:11:43 icinga1 kernel: [359392.196693] RDX: fffffffe00000001 RSI: 0000000000000000 RDI: ffff8803c8aec828
Oct  6 14:11:43 icinga1 kernel: [359392.196694] RBP: ffff88033194fe98 R08: 0000563d7cc698e0 R09: 0000563d7c0cc880
Oct  6 14:11:43 icinga1 kernel: [359392.196695] R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 0000000000000246 R12: 0000000000005401
Oct  6 14:11:43 icinga1 kernel: [359392.196697] R13: 00007ffef42a03b0 R14: ffff8803d1d9c500 R15: 0000000000000000
Oct  6 14:11:43 icinga1 kernel: [359392.196699] FS:  00002b64e6d8f000(0000) GS:ffff88043fc40000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Oct  6 14:11:43 icinga1 kernel: [359392.196700] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
Oct  6 14:11:43 icinga1 kernel: [359392.196701] CR2: 0000000000000000 CR3: 00000000bac36000 CR4: 00000000000406e0
Oct  6 14:11:43 icinga1 kernel: [359392.196784] Stack:
Oct  6 14:11:43 icinga1 kernel: [359392.196786]  ffff8802bf401600 ffff88033194fe20 ffffffff812276f2 ffff8802bf401600
Oct  6 14:11:43 icinga1 kernel: [359392.196788]  ffff8802bf401658 ffff8802bf401600 ffff88033194fe58 ffffffff8122795e
Oct  6 14:11:43 icinga1 kernel: [359392.196790]  ffff880428845000 0000000000000008 ffff8802cc420cb0 ffff88042d5d2920
Oct  6 14:11:43 icinga1 kernel: [359392.196792] Call Trace:
Oct  6 14:11:43 icinga1 kernel: [359392.196800]  [<ffffffff812276f2>] ? __dentry_kill+0x162/0x1e0
Oct  6 14:11:43 icinga1 kernel: [359392.196802]  [<ffffffff8122795e>] ? dput+0x1ee/0x220
Oct  6 14:11:43 icinga1 kernel: [359392.196818]  [<ffffffff81231224>] ? mntput+0x24/0x40
Oct  6 14:11:43 icinga1 kernel: [359392.196822]  [<ffffffff81211f00>] ? __fput+0x190/0x220
Oct  6 14:11:43 icinga1 kernel: [359392.196824]  [<ffffffff81223faf>] do_vfs_ioctl+0x29f/0x490
Oct  6 14:11:43 icinga1 kernel: [359392.196826]  [<ffffffff81211fce>] ? ____fput+0xe/0x10
Oct  6 14:11:43 icinga1 kernel: [359392.196830]  [<ffffffff8109f116>] ? task_work_run+0x86/0xa0
Oct  6 14:11:43 icinga1 kernel: [359392.196832]  [<ffffffff81224219>] SyS_ioctl+0x79/0x90
Oct  6 14:11:43 icinga1 kernel: [359392.196836]  [<ffffffff81843272>] entry_SYSCALL_64_fastpath+0x16/0x71
Oct  6 14:11:43 icinga1 kernel: [359392.196838] Code: 18 48 8b 41 60 48 85 c0 74 16 4c 89 ea 44 89 e6 48 89 df ff d0 3d fd fd ff ff 0f 85 da fd ff ff 48 89 df e8 3e 74 00 00 49 89 c7 <48> 8b 00 4c 8b 40 48 48 c7 c0 ea ff ff ff 4d 85 c0 74 22 44 89 
Oct  6 14:11:43 icinga1 kernel: [359392.196859] RIP  [<ffffffff814fa7c5>] tty_ioctl+0x375/0xc40
Oct  6 14:11:43 icinga1 kernel: [359392.196861]  RSP <ffff88033194fdf0>
Oct  6 14:11:43 icinga1 kernel: [359392.196862] CR2: 0000000000000000
Oct  6 14:11:43 icinga1 kernel: [359392.196865] ---[ end trace 72b7f0a8e26ab854 ]---
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bug report in the log says the issue is on `tty_ioctl`, so it is triggered when `ioctl` is called on a tty file descriptor. `Net::OpenSSH` uses a pseudo-tty when doing password authentication, so, a possible workaround for your problem would be to switch to a different authentication mechanism not requiring a tty as for instance public key authentication.

Also, the backtrace shows that the crash happens when manipulating the file system, so maybe your real problem is a corrupted file system triggering some kernel bug. You could try to force a `fsck` on the machine file systems or just to recreate them.

You didn't say which Linux distribution you are using neither the kernel version. You could try switching to a different one.

In any case, it is the first time anybody reports this problem, and Net::OpenSSH is used frequently with password authentication, so, unless you are using a pretty rare kernel version, there should be something special in your system that causes this bug to show up.

Comment: I marked this as the answer because I have the output from the script being written to a directory mounted with sshfs from a third server. There's two servers running this script, both writing to the directory from the third server.   The problem isn't the script, it's the sshfs directory. Thanks!